# Create new Objects with injected Spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am wondering what is the best way with Spring to inject values into a bean that is created new each time. I was going to use a factory to create the bean each time, but the resulting bean is not managed by spring. Meaning that annotations like `@Inject` are meaningless.

I can see two ways to do this (1) create the factory and have it manually just inject what is needed or (2) use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` after object creation.

(1)

```
@Named
public class TrackableJobFactory {

    public TrackableJob wrap(final Job runner) {
        return new TrackableJob(runner, bus);
    }


    private MessageBus bus;

    @Inject
    public void setMessageBus(MessageBus bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }
}

// ---- other class ---    
private final Job innerJob;
private final MessageBus bus;

public TrackableJob(Job job, MessageBus bus) {
    //...
}
```

I don't like how this mixes injected and non-injected beans. It is also a bit of a pain to maintain.

(2) you'd do a similar thing for the factory, but annotate the *actual job*. This means you'd end up with Spring annotations in a class not controlled by Spring. This is odd to me. :(

```
// in factory 
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory acbf; // injected by voodoo
    public TrackableJob wrap(final Job runner) {
        TrackableJob j = new TrackableJob(runner);
        acbf.autowireBean(j);
        return j;
    }

// ---- other class ---    
private final Job innerJob;

@Inject
private MessageBus bus;

public TrackableJob(Job job) {
    //...
}
```

Is there a part of Spring that fixes this? I don't see that the Factory interfaces are able to do anything else, but there is a lot of things and stuff. :)

Comment: Sounds like you want prototype scope.

Comment: You might want the rethink some parts of the app, is this really what you want? You can use [`@Configurable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) to do this, but it is a fiddle to setup and might impact performance.